# MYSQL Syntax - Insert statement

Tags: php, mysql, syntax, insert

Struggling with a simple insert command, i'm getting the error

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to 
your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'All In: 
The Poker Movie, tells the story of poker focusing on why one of our nat' 
at line 2"
```

Basically passing film information into a table, here is the code -

```
$query1 = "INSERT INTO Films_Info (Films_ID,FilmName, FilmRelease, Synopsis,Poster,CritScore,AudScore,Director,Studio,IMDB,date_added_db) 
VALUES ('',$Film_Name', '$Film_Release','$filmsynopsis','$film_image','$film_critic','$film_audience','$film_director','$film_studio','$film_imdbID','')";
$runquery1 = mysql_query($query1)or die(mysql_error());
```

Thanks guys

Comment: `$Film_Name'` this bit is missing the opening quote I believe

Comment: You should also pass through `mysql_real_escape_string()` not par-sey for any sql injections you may have but to escape any quotes ect that will break your query.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like that you are missing an ' before $Film_Name. Can you add the missing apostrophe?

Comment: That fixed that error but its still giving a sql syntax error, saying its near a part of the entered data?

Answer (score 1):

If you have phpmyadmin enabled on you server, you can paste the code into the SQL-Field to get syntax highlighting on the SQL query.